# I am getting an 'illegal start of expression' error

Tags: java

So the thing is I'm trying to get this program to work to type out the numbers given in words. i am constantly getting an illegal start of expression error.
I am a beginner and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the excerpt from my program

```
if(n>=1000)
    {
        System.out.println("OUT OF RANGE");
    }
    else
    {
        String result="", h=" ", t=" ", o=" ";
        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        String ones[]= {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
        String teens[]={"eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};
        String tens[]={"ten","twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};
        if(n>=100 && n<1000)
        {
            a=n/100;
            result = [a-1]+"hundred"; //the problem occurs here.
            n=n%100;
        }
```

Comment: You are missing `hundreds`, as in `hundreds[a-1]`.

Comment: What do you want for result String? '[' is not a legal start.

Answer (score 1):

Umm. I found the mistake. Sorry for wasting your time.

It will be

```
 result = ones[a-1]+"hundred";
```

From

```
result = [a-1]+"hundred";
```

Thanks anyways.